# iOS init MKMapView with user location and proper scale/span

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I init my mapviewControler like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.firstShow=TRUE;
    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    self.cllmng=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.cllmng.delegate=self;
    self.cllmng.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    self.cllmng.distanceFilter=50;
    [self.cllmng startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and I make mapviewControler implement CLLocationManagerDelegate, and implement `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` in my code.

The problem I have is that I want to init map view **centred on current user location with a proper scale**. I intend to do this by

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
CLLocation * currentLoci=[locations lastObject];
MKCoordinateRegion r;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 1;
span.longitudeDelta = 1;
r.span = span;
CLLocationCoordinate2D c;
c.longitude=currentLoci.coordinate.longitude;
c.latitude=currentLoci.coordinate.latitude;
r.center = c;
[self.mapView setRegion:r animated:YES];
}
```

But **sometimes**, after  [self.cllmng startUpdatingLocation] called in the -(void) viewDidload, I cannot get a call of `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` immediately. Thus, the map view just init showing user location but showing the whole Australia. How can I set the scale/span in the init of map view even `didUpdateLocations` is not triggered? THX!

Comment: Why are you using a CLLocationManager to get the user location?  Since you are setting showsUserLocation to YES on the map view, it will call its own delegate method didUpdateUserLocation which should be in sync with the blue dot.

Comment: @Anna. just in order to get current location and use it to make a proper region in didUpdateLocation method. Craig has given what I want. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INstead of modifying the region yourself using a CLLocation manager you could just set the `trackingMode` of the mapView and it'll center and zoom in on your position automatically. It will be possible for the user to disable the tracking mode if they start dragging the map around, but you can disable user interaction if you really want them to have no control. Here is how to do it

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode:animated:

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11.x Swift 4.0 Craigs answer, updated.

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Not so obvious I fear.